# cracks at edges of shader material in THREE.js

Tags: animation, three.js, glsl

I'm using a shader material to wrap a rectangular texture around a torus in the expected way, gluing edge to edge.  The problem is that at the edges, the texture doesn't quite wrap around, and there's this little glowing crack which looks like scanning.

I've isolated the problem and found that it's in my fragment shader.  I need to be able to shift the uv values freely in my actual program, so i have some lines in the fragment shader normalizing the uv values to keep them between 0 and 1.  However, this results in the unfortunate texture cracks.  I am having trouble understanding why... in the beginning shouldn't the uv coordinates be inbetween 0 and 1? Even without any rotation, going on, these lines cause the cracks.  Remove the lines, no cracks... but I can't remove them if I'm rotating the texture because then I get a totally undesired effect.  hoping someone could explain how these lines in the fragment shader are causing the cracks and what I can do to achieve the same behavior but avoid the cracks, I'm a real novice in glsl.

the problem occurs in the below, with the if statements.

```
  uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
  uniform float rotX;
  uniform float rotY;
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main(){
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    uv.x = uv.x + rotX;
    uv.y = uv.y + rotY;
    if (uv.y > 1.)
                uv.y = uv.y -1.;
            if (uv.y < 0.)
                uv.y = uv.y + 1.;
            if (uv.x > 1.)
                uv.x = uv.x -1.;
            if(uv.x < 0.)
                uv.x = uv.x + 1.;
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(uv.x,uv.y));
        }
```

Here's a very distilled [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/807t60k8/6/)
 reproducing the problem and showing a meridian texture rotation on the torus.

Comment: a picture is worth a 1000 words!

Comment: a pic and 1000 words in javascript... priceless )

Comment: added some more description. hope that helps

Comment: ok identified the problem and fiddled it! Still not sure how to correct it, but it seems pretty simple, i'm just ignorant of glsl!

Comment: Ok, tentative answer is to remove these problem lines (equivalent to appling fract function, i realized) and simulate glTexParameteri behavior in THREE.js by appying texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping and likewise for texture.wrapT.  Would be happy if someone could still explain why fract-ing the uvs isn't working.